# What flavours of Linear Logic are algebraizable?

Tags: algebraic-logic, linear-logic

I am a theoretical linguistics student and I have been working in the last few years on an improved model of natural language semantics, but I am missing a final mathematical insight in order to wrap up my work.

The theory implements the intuitionistic multiplicative fragment of Linear Logic, i.e. LL($\otimes, \multimap$) and I was asking myself whether it is algebraizable or maybe, before considering that, whether one of the proposed interpretations of LL($\otimes, \multimap$) (quantales, GoI, Petri nets, game theory and possibly others) is considered algebraic. My final goal is working with sets of equations over an algebraic structure interpreting LL($\otimes, \multimap$).

Please tell me if you need any more information.

Comment: What do mean by multiplicative-implicative fragment of LL? Maybe do you refer to IMLL, the _intuitionistic_ multiplicative fragment of LL?

Comment: It is defined by Asudeh 2012 as LL with only ⊗, ⅋ and ⊸ and he calls it MILL, but I think it is a convention in linguistics and not in mathematics.

Comment: In [this 2012 paper](http://www.sas.rochester.edu/lin/sites/asudeh/handouts/asudeh-jerusalem-2012-ho.pdf) (see p. 10), Asudeh defines MILL as  the multiplicative _intuitionistic_ fragment of linear logic, whose connective are only $\otimes$ and $\multimap$.

Comment: I see, thank you for pointing out my error, I must have mixed it up with some paper in [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ub3mQ51za6sC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), which has been my latest main reference. I am correcting my question with your reference for now, for the sake of clarity and since I do not have the possibility of double checking right now.